# Отображение объекта Bitmap с использованием технологии Blazor

Tags: c#, bitmap, razor, blazor

Есть задача отобразить на Web-странице объект типа bitmap, который периодически меняется.
В С# для десктоп элементов я бы подписался на событие paint и отрисовывал бы его вот так:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_bitmapLock)
        {
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(_bitmap.Width, _bitmap.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bitmap, e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y , e.ClipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

Но на Blazor я никак не могу найти как это сделать. Я пробовал брать элемент

`<img src='tutorial.png'>`

Записывать bitmap в tutorial.png  и пытаться вызывать InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged), когда объект bitmap меняется, чтобы перерисовать его с новым src. Но это так не работает. Мне удалось добиться обновления всей страницы, но выглядит это ужасно. Пробовал использовать компоненты Radzen(вроде бы они должны динамически меняться), но тоже без успеха.  Какие вообще способы существуют по отображение на web  bitmap в Blazor? Может есть иной путь?

Comment: Отличный вопрос. Мне кажется в вебе ничего аналогичного нет для подобного отображения. Всё что можно посоветовать - это рисовать на canvas.

Comment: Рендерьте битмап в картинку и AJAX запросами к серверу обновляйте.

Comment: @AK получается именно так;(  Спасибо.

Comment: [Blazor event handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - по-моему, это то, что нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не совсем понял, как это может помочь. У меня нет проблемы получить событие (момента изменения src). Есть проблема именно в отрисовке.